# Insert Link to Audio versus Embed Audio Player

Tags: media, media-library, visual-editor, embed, audio

I've run into a very odd problem. One of my authors will upload an audio file in the Media Manager, and instead of giving the option to embed a media player, it just inserts a link to the audio file. If he deletes the link and reopens Media Manager, the Embed Media Player option reappears. I have not been able to replicate this in any other user account, and I've had him log out, clear his cache and cookies, and log back in to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Try e.g. to see if it's browser or audio type related? Any console errors? Otherwise I vote to close, as this error sounds too localized. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't been able to figure this one out, so I'm going to go ahead and close it. Seems to be localized to a specific computer/user account.